# code to move an item from one parent node to another parent one based on current date checking

Tags: sitecore

I have a requirement to move an item from one parent node to another in the content tree based on date checking. How could we achieve that by C# coding?

Comment: You should add your codes that you already tried. Also you need to add [tag:C#] with the question.

Answer (score 1):

The code below should get you pointed in the right direction:

```csharp
var currentDb = Sitecore.Data.Database.GetDatabase("master");
var newParentItem = currentDb.GetItem("/sitecore/content/NewParent");
Sitecore.Context.Item.MoveTo(newParentItem);
```

Comment: Many Thanks Lan.it really helped me a lot.this is what we call as unconditional support/help